# Apache Spark set dataFrame from oracle database to elastic search

Tags: python, oracle, apache-spark, pyspark

While trying to write or set the dataFrame from oracle database to elasticsearch using Apache spark , I am getting this error message:

Note: I using Elasticsearch version 8.8.2 , Spark V 3.4.3, python V 3.8 , pySpark V 3.4.1 and Scala V 2.12

The code below:

```
def write(self, dataFrame):
        """start indexing new dataSource to Elasticsearch with all required steps

        Arguments:
            dataFrame {Spark DataFrame} -- source dataFrame

        Raises:
            Error -- may raise unexpected types of errors
        """
        # create new index name for this dataFrame
        self.currentIndex = self.generateIndex()
        # set Source document details before indexing
        try:
            count = dataFrame.count()
        except Exception as err:
            self.terminate("Failed to dataframe count", error=err)
        self.__updateSource(key=Source.rowNumber, value=count)

        # inform application about importing percent
        thread = Thread(target=self.__pubPercent)
        thread.start()
        # emit number of rows
        rows = self.document.get(Source.rowNumber)
        # index this dataFrame into Elasticsearch
        partitions = 10 if rows < 10**5 else 100
        try:
            self.setDataFrame(self.currentIndex, dataFrame.repartition(partitions))
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            # wait thread till finish
            thread.join()
```

```
def setDataFrame(self, index, dataFrame, idField=None):
        """Create new index using dataFrame
        Spark doesn't accept to add dataFrame documents in existing index
        So, it'll delete index if exists

        Arguments:
            index {str} -- Index Name
            dataFrame {Spark dateFrame} -- index documents

        Keyword Arguments:
            idField {str} -- Name of identity field (default:None)

        Raises:
            Error -- may raise unexpected types of errors
        """
        # delete old index if exists
        esClient.deleteIndex(index)

        # trying to set index mapping
        esClient.putMapping(index, dataFrame.dtypes)

        # write data frame to elasticsearch

        writer = (
            dataFrame.write.format(self.SPARK_SQL_FORMAT)
            .option(self.RESOURSE_KEY, "{}/{}".format(index, index))
            .option(self.NODE_KEY, self.__host)
            .option(self.PORT_KEY, self.__port)
        )
        # check if there's identity field or not

        if idField:
            writer = writer.option(self.MAPPING_ID_KEY, idField)

        # export dataFrame into Elastic
        writer.save()
```

pip list:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhe3Z.png)

spark :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGg9M.png)

scala version :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0EPn.png)

The Exception :

```
An error occurred while calling o68.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:228)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:856)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:387)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:360)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:247)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

Can someone let me know if anyone faced this issue and how they resolved it?

Comment: The error refers to you using an incorrect Scala compiled dependency. Please show your actual dependency list, not just the numbers

Comment: I have modified the question now , you can check it @OneCricketeer

Comment: The Spark output says Scala 2.12, so this is the version of your Spark-ES dependency, for example, that you need. Python/Pip versions are unrelated to the error you are seeing. You also don't need Elasticsearch python clients since Spark uses the Java libraries, not the Python ones